# Can we use the pretrained WavLM on Portuguese?

Tags: deep-learning, speaker, speaker-verfication

I wan to try WavLM for 2 tasks:

1. Speaker Verification
2. Speech embeddings

If I understand it correctly, the WavLM pre-trained model was trained on English.

so if I want to use it for my missions, do I need to fine-tune it for Portuguese?
or because the basic was trained only on English - I need to train it from scratch on Portuguese?